# How to use "rest_framework" routers with Django 2

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am aware that "Django 2 with router url patterns has changed". I cant manage to work with Router because I am getting an error :

```
    'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

I have written a basic model and after that I have created an api folder, I have prepared files `"views.py"`:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from yogavidya.apps.articles.models import Article
from .serializers import ArticleSerializer
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

class ArticleUpdateView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
  lookup_field = 'pk'
  serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
  queryset = Article.objects.all()

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api/articles', ArticleUpdateView, base_name='api-articles')
```

after I have  `urls.py` :

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from .views import ArticleUpdateView
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'articles/(?:page-(?P<page_number>\d+)/)?$', ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name='article-update'),
]
```

now I want to add the api to project `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from yogavidya.apps.articles import views

from .views import home,home_files, pricing
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('articles/', include('yogavidya.apps.articles.urls', namespace="articles")),
)

urlpatterns += [
    path('api/articles/', include('yogavidya.apps.articles.api.urls', namespace="api-articles")),
```

]

How can I set `app_name = 'api-articles'` as a global variable and manage to import app_name in my `urls.py`?

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5659?

Comment: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5609#issuecomment-359032198 is a proposed workaround

Comment: yep but tutorials I follow and documents get along well. Django 2.0 and documents of rest_framework needs lots of effort.